# Eloquent return rows where relationship exists

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a parent table and a child table with the eloquent models set up as:

```
class Parent extends Eloquent {

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('child');
    }

}

class Child extends Eloquent {

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('parent');
    }

}
```

How can I return only parent rows that have 1 or more children?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations) You do it like this :

```
$parents = Parent::has('children')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had one like this, where I was listing children from a parent, but I only wanted to list a child if it also had children (grandChildren).

originally:

```
$parent->children
```

didn't work:

```
$parent->children->has('grandChildren')->get()
```

worked:

```
$parent->children()->has('grandChildren')->get()
```

Note the inclusion of `()`.